# How do I convert between global and local coordinates when working with NSScreens?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am writing an app that maniuplates window positions and am adding multi-monitor support.

To facilitate this, I have the "local" window position (relative to the frame of an NSScreen) and I need to translate this to the "global" window position (relative to the position from which all monitor positions are designated, which I believe is the lower-left corner of the first (0th) index of [NSScreen screens]).

I would like to use a single coordinate system to store my window positions and do this relative to the global coordinate system, then translate to the local coordinate system for display.

What are the helper methods to translate coordinates between an NSScreen frame and the global screen-space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need -[NSScreen frame]. The frame's origin is relative to the frame origin of the zero screen ([[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0]).

By the way, NSWindow's frame is already in a global coordinate system relative to the frame origin of the zero screen. It sounds like you might be reinventing that, but you may have good reasons for doing it.

As an example, here are two functions that would convert global points, and points relative to a screen's frame:

```
extern NSPoint MyConvertLocalScreenPointToGlobal(NSScreen *screen, NSPoint local) {
    NSPoint global = {
        .x = [screen frame].origin.x + local.x,
        .y = [screen frame].origin.y + local.y,
    };
    return global;
}

extern NSPoint MyConvertGlobalScreenPointToLocal(NSScreen *screen, NSPoint global) {
    NSPoint local = {
        .x = global.x - [screen frame].origin.x,
        .y = global.y - [screen frame].origin.y,
    };
    return local;
}
```

Comment: In one of my apps that deals with multi-monitors, I just do everything in global coordinates (which screen frame's are in). If only have coordinates relative to individual screens, you'll just have to do some simple maths to add them to the screen’s frame coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to get a global offset by adding a screen relative position to the screen's frame origin. That will result in a point relative to the zero screen's origin.